# Eclipse plugin to display failed JUnit tests in package explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have a daily test run in Hudson/Jenkins that outputs a JUnit XML report. I would like to have the results of those tests show in the Eclipse package explorer.

I can import the test result and have it shown in a JUnit view in Eclipse, but I'd like to have it more visible.

Here's what I'm after: When a developer is working on class X in plugin Y it should be visible directly in the package explorer that there is a failed test in this class/package/plugin. Kind of like compilation errors are handled (but perhaps slightly less obtrusive).

Comment: Any plugin will (most likely) only be able to show the test case that has failed (the test method) but not the method in your code that caused the failure. So I'm not sure if a plugin, that would annotated the test methods, really adds a lot value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about integrating Jenkins in Eclipse. There's the [Hudson/Jenkins connector](http://tasktop.com/connectors/hudson-jenkins.php) that allows to manage a Hudson or Jenkins instance that you can buy.

Other solution could be to install the Hudson Mylyn Connector integrator (in incubation status) to see the build status in Eclipse (was in incubation status). Using it you will be able to view the test results in the regular Eclipse JUnit view, examine the build's console output, etc. You could install this simply using the Eclipse update-site and searching for Hudson/Jenking in the Mylyn Integrations.

Hope to help you.